# Stop Driver Process after - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When trying to initialize the ChromeDriver to run selenium tests in C#, this mismatch error causes the chromedriver executable to remain running.

I've modified the code to catch the exception and then call `Driver.Quit()` however this is having no effect to the executing process.

How do I prevent the driver from becoming a zombie process (not technically zombie).

Comment: What did you tried ? Adding some code wouldn't hurt somebody.

Comment: I've run into this issue before and I believe it's one of the known issues with chromedriver. I had to create a `finally` block that executes `taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe` to kill all of the hanging tasks.

Comment: Can you please provide your code snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked around this issue with:

```
using NeoSmart.AsyncLock;
// ...
private static AsyncLock driverlock = new AsyncLock();

using (driverlock.Lock())
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58665122/stop-driver-process-after-session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-on
    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver");
    try
    {
        Browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        var newProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver");
        newProcess.Select(x => x.Id)
            .Except(process.Select(x => x.Id))
            .ToList().ForEach(x => Process.GetProcessById(x).Kill());
        throw;
    }

}
```

Filed: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7748